# ps2pdf with several input files

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

At least with gs 9.06 ps2pdf does not work like this any more:

```
cat foo1.ps foo2.ps | ps2pdf - out.pdf
```

How can I convert several Postscript files to one PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here: [ps2pdf Docs](http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Ps2pdf.htm#Limitations)

This works, here called from Python:

```
import subprocess
cmd=['gs', '-q', '-dSAFER', '-dNOPAUSE', '-dBATCH', 
         '-dDisableFAPI',
         '-sOutputFile=%s' % pdf,
         '-sDEVICE=pdfwrite', 
         '-c', '.setpdfwrite', '-f'
         ]
cmd.extend(ps_files)
subprocess.check_call(cmd)
```